# How do I summarize spend across the year for each vendor?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to summarize spend amounts from my database across the year for each of my vendors.  So far I can pull the spend amount for each vendor but for some reason it just shows up as individual rows instead of one row with the SUM Of the Spend for the year.  Here is an example:

Can someone help here ?  I am trying to get the some of each vendor as one row with the SUM of the spend for that year for sql server.  here is my query :

```
SELECT max([VendorName]) as VendorName
   ,SUM(CAST(GrossSpend as float)) as Gross
   ,YEAR(ScheduledRunDateStart)as YEAR 
FROM [QAData].[dbo].[ES_GIP_20090101_20150326_20140326]
  -
Group BY VendorName,ScheduledRunDateStart
ORDER BY  Year DESC
```

Currently I'm unable to add a picture to help show what I mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expect the below will work better:

```
SELECT [VendorName]

,SUM(CAST(GrossSpend as float)) as Gross

,YEAR(ScheduledRunDateStart)as YEAR 

FROM [QAData].[dbo].[ES_GIP_20090101_20150326_20140326] -

Group BY VendorName,YEAR(ScheduledRunDateStart)

ORDER BY YEAR(ScheduledRunDateStart), Vendor DESC
```